# Chrome Tab/Menu/URL bar and web pages have got really big

Tags: google-chrome, 15.04

On a Dell XPS 13 (9333), I am running Ubuntu 15.04 and Google Chrome Stable and since yesterday after some updates, Google Chrome has gone all weird on me.

The Tab/Menu/URL bar and web pages have got really big. I have played with the zoom settings and set zoom to 50% and that has fixed the web page sizing, but Tab/Menu/URL bar is still massive.

I have tried a Reset Chrome, in the Settings menu, and also removing and reinstalling Chrome.

No issues with Firefox or other applications.

Comment: I though l had fixed it with the --force-device-scale-factor, but it seems very random whether it works or not.

Comment: I've got the same issue after upgrading Chrome stable to 43.0.2357.124 64-bit. Executing $ google-chrome --force-device-scale-factor seems to does the trick for me.

Comment: It worked once for me, but doesn't seem to work subsequently.

Comment: removing google-chrome-stable and using google-chrome-beta has worked for me at the moment

Comment: A similar question is http://askubuntu.com/questions/634999/ .

Comment: @DawidLorenz This worked for me, very easy solution.

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and issue the following commands:

```
sudo -i
apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
cd /var/cache/apt/archives
dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_43.0.2357.81-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As [Dawid says in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634502/chrome-tab-menu-url-bar-and-web-pages-have-got-really-big/962013#comment905103_634502) above, try running

```
$ google-chrome --force-device-scale-factor
```

This worked for me, and I remapped my browser shortcut. I am also on an XPS13, and am running 16.04