# Google Chrome's address bar has doubled in size. How can I fix this?

Tags: updates, firefox, google-chrome, appearance

With recent updates on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation, Google Chrome has changed in appearance such that its address bar has doubled in size. You can see Chrome on the left side and Firefox on the right side in the following screenshot:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: @Ron That's not the issue. Look at the size of the address bar of Firefox and then look at the size of the address bar of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The identical issue has been addressed [in a previous post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634502/chrome-tab-menu-url-bar-and-web-pages-have-got-really-big#comment905350_634502). In comments, it has been suggested to remove `google-chrome-stable` and to use `google-chrome-beta` as an interim solution.